# Android emulator Internet connection

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am using win 7 64 bit OS, using Android 2.2 my emulator couldn't be connected to computer. I am using internet behind proxy server. I change the APN setting by filling proxy setting of my machine. But still I can't be connected to the internet Please any one who can help me? Thanks for your answers.

Comment: search through StackOverflow, this question has been asked (and answered) numerous times before (hint - look through my answers)

Answer (score 0):

You can set the proxy in the emulator.
This link describes all the options https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking.html.

One way is when you run the emulator from the command line add -http-proxy:

```
emulator.exe -avd YOUR_AVD_NAME_HERE -http-proxy http://<machineName>:<port>
```

or

```
emulator.exe -avd YOUR_AVD_NAME_HERE -http-proxy http://<username>:<password>@<machineName>:<port>
```

And consider if you computer has more than one network interface. Maybe your emulator is trying to use one that is not connect, its very common. The simplest solution is just to disable the ETHERNET interface if you are using WIFI interface. Other way is to change the priority of your interfaces in the operational system. In Windows 10 you can do this by:

1. Goto Control Panel > Network and Internet > Network Connections
2. Right click the desired connection (Higher Priority Connection)
3. Click Properties > Internet Protocol Version 4
4. Click Properties > Advanced
5. Uncheck 'Automatic Metric'
6. Enter 1 in 'Interface Metric'
7. Click OK
   Repeat for the Lower Priority Connection, but this time put 20 into the 'Interface Metric'
   You'll now use the higher priority connection as a default.